# VMs in different NATs

Tags: networking, vmware, nat, vmware-workstation, hole-punching

I want to simulate three computers, everyone behind a different NAT, in order to test hole punching.

I want a server that its address is know to the other two VMs, but the two VMs to be in separate NATs.

Any ideas on how to configure this in workstation 7 ?

Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

Honestly, if your three VMs are each under separate NATs and one VM has a public ipv4 address, then there is nothing specific you need to configure within workstation 7. You are ready to go to test hole punching.

Comment: the problem is that workstation says I can only setup one NAT in my network configuration. I don't know why there is this limitation.

Comment: But, isn't the NAT an external device to your station?

Comment: Yes, But I require two, and for some reason VMWARE allows only one. I see that you have many experience with nat traversal, how did you test your code was working (simulate 2 peers behind nat communicating with a known server) ? Also, any chance you have recommendations on a framework in C++ (is PJNATH good)?

Comment: I am not really sure I understand your architecture, why do you need to install the NAT on your VM? And are VM's on different machines or the same physical machine? If they are on the same physical machine, what type of ip address is assigned to them?

Comment: I don't want to install the NAT in my VMs, I want each VM (Alice and Bob) to be behind a different (domain) to really simulate the hole punching. I want to run all my VMs on my local machine. Basically I want to simulate on my computer an entire network configuration of a server and 2 client behind different NATs.

Comment: This is very heavy. You should investigate network simulation tools.

Comment: Thanks for your input. Any chance to get a recommendation for a C++ framework for NAT traversal ?

Comment: No, sorry. I am not working with C++ since university...